# Celery discover tasks in files with other filenames

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm starting to have so many celery tasks that I want to break them down into smaller files instead of having them in a big `tasks.py`, but I don't manage to get celery to discover them.

Working structure:

```
proj/
    app/
        tasks.py
```

Structure I would like to work:

```
proj/
    app/
        tasks/
            __init__.py
            task1.py
            task2.py
            ...
```

But here celery does not find my tasks. I tried setting the `CELERY_IMPORTS`, but then I have to specify each file, and there is so many files. Same if I import each file contents into `__init__.py`. I would like all tasks to be automatically discovered, or at least all tasks in files in the tasks directory.

I could of course list all files in each tasks directory into `CELERY_IMPORTS` but that seems rather ugly.

Any ideas if this is possible in a nice way?

Comment: this is old but works fine with newer versions of celery (e.g.: Celery  v3.1.18 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've given up on finding a nice solution and instead wrote a function that I call and populate CELERY_IMPORTS with. It's not nice, but it works.

Here's the code for future reference:

```
import os

def detect_tasks(project_root):
    tasks = []
    file_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'apps')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for filename in files:
            if os.path.basename(root) == 'tasks':
                if filename != '__init__.py' and filename.endswith('.py'):
                    task = os.path.join(root, filename)\
                        .replace(os.path.dirname(project_root) + '/', '')\
                        .replace('/', '.')\
                        .replace('.py', '')
                    tasks.append(task)
    return tuple(tasks)
```

And then in settings:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = detect_tasks(project_root)
```

Where project_root would be something like this:

```
project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: if you put it in the settings it will run on every request, and will do reads form the hard drive.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't remember if settings is read every time, if so cache or memoize it would work.

Comment: settings is not reloaded for every request. it's imported once when the celery worker is started

Answer (score 16):

You could just define `__all__` in your `tasks/__init__.py` file. Without additional celery settings changes.

For example:

```py
# app/tasks/__init__.py

from .file_with_tasks_1 import task1, task2
from .file_with_tasks_2 import task3

__all__ = [
    'task1',
    'task2',
    'task3',
]
```

Tested on celery v4.4.6

Comment: Why importing tasks with the name when why are we providing in the string? How to pass all the tasks at once.

Comment: @SirajAlam I tested and apparently, only importing the task itself works. I put the `__all__` part as comment and it worked. The opposite didn't. The `__all__` part is just there to tell what is exportable from `tasks` in case you do something like `from ....../tasks import *`

Answer (score 8):

The only reason that celery defaults to searching tasks.py is the default argument to autodiscover_tasks:

```
./loaders/base.py:def autodiscover_tasks(packages, related_name='tasks'):
```

If you use the configuration recommended by the docs you can just call autodiscover_tasks with non-default values for related_name for the different file names where you expect to have tasks.  For example here is our celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('app')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks2')
```

Comment: This does not solve my initial question. I want to automatically register 100 files distributed in folders named tasks over multiple apps. I'd have to write `related_name='tasks.task1'` for each file, so it's a nice tip but it does not help with the initial question.

Answer (score 4):

```
proj/
    app/
        tasks/
            __init__.py
            task1.py
            task2.py
            ...
```

> if your files structure as above, you can do as following

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

app = Celery('celery')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

for app_name in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    if app_name.startswith('django'):
        continue
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(app_name + '/tasks'):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('__') or file.endswith('.pyc') or not file.endswith('.py'):
                continue
            file = file[:-3]
            app.autodiscover_tasks([app_name + '.tasks'], related_name=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried code snippet from @oloform. It is not working for me. I have got very simple idea. Since celery looks for tasks.py for any tasks. I am defining tasks in any file but I am adding it in tasks.py like,

```
# tasks.py
from app.utilities.somename import upload_done
from project.celery import app
app.task(upload_done)
```

It is easily visible in celery logs,

```
 -------------- celery@######## v3.1.18 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- ###############
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         project:0x2aae5c0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   django://localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:     djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . app.utilities.somename.upload_done
```

It is dirty way but, it works.

Comment: What is not working for you? I'm still using the solution and for me it's fine. I can not use this suggestion since the project is built of a bunch of apps and each app might have it's own tasks folder with unlimited python files with tasks in them so I wanted it more dynamic than that.