# Celery Beat not Scheduling Task in Django Project

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm working on a Django project where I'm using Celery for task scheduling. I have a periodic task that should run every minute, but it seems that Celery Beat is not picking up this task. Here's my setup:

tasks.py:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from ..apps.scraper.scrapers.updates import get_updates
from .settings import app

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "get_updates": {
        "task": "..apps.scraper.scrapers.updates.get_updates",
        "schedule": crontab(minute="*/1"),  # Run every 1 minute
    },
}
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "manga_project.settings")

app = Celery("manga_project")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.broker_url = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
```

updates.py:

```
@app.task
def get_updates():
    print("Looking for manga updates...")
    mangas = Manga.objects.all()
    for manga in mangas:
        print("Checking ", manga.title, " ...")
        scrape_chapters("str", manga.url)
```

I expect the get_updates task to run every minute, but it's not happening. When I start Celery Beat, it doesn't seem to pick up this task when I check the debbuger.

I tried restarting celery and adding some error handling, but the tasks just simply doesnt get picked up so I am not sure how to handle this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`autodiscover_tasks` Searches a list of packages for a "tasks.py" module which is default `related_name` for search.

As your tasks reside in `updates.py`

so change `app.autodiscover_tasks()` to `app.autodiscover_tasks(related_name='updates')` to check for updates.py

read [autodiscover_tasks](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks) parameters and what it does

You can take a look here if you have task files are not in the same relative location
[Celery discover tasks in files with other filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078549/celery-discover-tasks-in-files-with-other-filenames)

and of course, you can change the `updates.py` to `tasks.py` if that works